# OTRS.log pm file not found/could not be loaded

Tags: perl, otrs

i'm using OTRS 3.2.11 on windows 2008 server. i did some modification on the Kernel/Output/HTML/NotificationUIDCheck.pm file to get rid of the Red warninig message that says "don't use superuser account...".
now the message is no longer appearing but the log file is showing this message continiously:

```
[Sun May 18 07:59:54 2014][Error][Kernel::Output::HTML::Layout::NavigationBar][2932] Module Kernel/Output/HTML/NotificationUIDCheck.pm not found/could not be loaded!
```

and here is the NotificationUIDCheck.pm running:

```
package Kernel::Output::HTML::NotificationUIDCheck;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
my ( $Type, %Param ) = @_;

# allocate new hash for object
my $Self = {};
bless( $Self, $Type );

# get needed objects
for (qw(ConfigObject LogObject DBObject LayoutObject UserID)) {
    $Self->{$_} = $Param{$_} || die "Got no $_!";
}
return $Self;
}
```

the original file was like:

```
package Kernel::Output::HTML::NotificationUIDCheck;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
my ( $Type, %Param ) = @_;

# allocate new hash for object
my $Self = {};
bless( $Self, $Type );

# get needed objects
for (qw(ConfigObject LogObject DBObject LayoutObject UserID)) {
    $Self->{$_} = $Param{$_} || die "Got no $_!";
}
return $Self;
}

sub Run {
my ( $Self, %Param ) = @_;

# return if it's not root@localhost
return '' if $Self->{UserID} != 1;

# show error notfy, don't work with user id 1
return $Self->{LayoutObject}->Notify(
    Priority => 'Error',
    Link     => '$Env{"Baselink"}Action=AdminUser',
    Data =>
        '$Text{"Don\'t use the Superuser account to work with OTRS! Create new Agents  and work with these accounts instead."}',
);
}

1;
```

I guess something is missing can you help guys find out how to fix it please!!!

Comment: What appears to be missing in your modified code is the `Run` subroutine

Comment: where should i add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure why you want to fix the 'Don't use the superuser account' warning with something other than don't using the superuser account!!

There's a reason that you actually don't want to use this account, and it is that ACLs do not apply when you use it, and also the SuperUser account would be by default the owner of all tickets created by email and/or the customer portal.

And even then, if you don't want to see the error message, you should probably add this to your `Kernel/Config.pm` file to disable the check:

```
$Self->{'Frontend::NotifyModule'}->{'200-UID-Check'}
```

This way there are no code changes needed.

Comment: OK!! i have to agree that it is not the propre way to fix it. but the Admin>sysconfig>fronted::notifymodule###200-UID check is gray...can not check or uncheck the box.

Comment: Ah! You're right, you can't disable that config option. Modified the solution to address this.

Comment: i added the line to the config.pm file and delete the cache and rebuild the config but it still gray!! am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it's gray, but the notify module is also no longer active. If you want to have it disabled in SysConfig you'd need to add an XML file. Putting the option in Config.pm should really just do it though.

Comment: Ohhh...Ok...thank you!! didn't try it..but i will do it later!!

Answer (score -1):

i got it fixed guys it is true the `sub run` was missing and here below the full code working with no log error:

```
package Kernel::Output::HTML::NotificationUIDCheck;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
my ( $Type, %Param ) = @_;

# allocate new hash for object
my $Self = {};
bless( $Self, $Type );

# get needed objects
for (qw(ConfigObject LogObject DBObject LayoutObject UserID)) {
    $Self->{$_} = $Param{$_} || die "Got no $_!";
}
return $Self;
}

sub Run {
my ( $Self, %Param ) = @_;

# return if it's not root@localhost
return '' if $Self->{UserID} != 1;
}
1;
```